# Removing consecutive blank rows from StringBuilder

Tags: c#

I have a Stringbuilder object that has been populated from a text file.
How can I check the StringBuilder object for and remove consecutive "blank" lines.

i.e

```
Line 1: This is my text
Line 2:
Line 3: Another line after the 1st blank one
Line 4: 
Line 5:
Line 6: Next line after 2 blank lines
```

(Line numbers given as reference only)

The blank line on Line 2 is fine, but I would like to remove the duplicate blank line, on Line 5, and so on.

If for argument sake Line 6 would have also been a blank line, and a Line 7 had a value, I would like Blank Line 5 and Blank Line 6 removed, so that there would only be 1 blank line between the Line 3 and Line 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just don't Append() them to the StringBuilder when you read the file.

Comment: Thanks, but it is another component that reads in the text file that has a .GetStringBuilder() method. 

Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have to already have the file contents in a StringBuilder?

It would be nicer to be able to read line-by-line. Something like:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetLinesFromFile(string fileName)
{
  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
  {
    string line = null;
    bool previousLineWasBlank = false;
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      if (!previousLineWasBlank && string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
      {
        yield return line;
      }

      previousLineWasBlank = string.IsNullOrEmpty(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can read in your text (which has had dupe blank lines removed) like this:

```
foreach (var line in GetLinesFromFile("myFile.txt"))
{
  Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Note: I'm only illustrating a technique here. There are other considerations: e.g. my iterator method holds the file open while the consumers are processing the foreach. This is nice and memory efficient (more so than reading into a string for example) as you are only dealing with one line at a time, but not ideal for files that take a long time to process.

Comment: Yes, it would, but is another component that reads in the text file that has a .GetStringBuilder() method. 

Sorry, forgot to mention that. I will keep this in mind for when reading in text files myself.

Comment: +1 For using Yield. @Riaan, I would suggest that you ignore/rewrite the other component. Out of the answers entered so far, this one is by far the most efficient and it leaves the door open for using buffers for larger files. The StringBuilder approach will perform much slower than streaming.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not very efficient, but it's easy.

```
while(sb.ToString().Contains(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine))
{
    sb = sb.Replace(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: "not very efficient" is a rather large understatement.

Comment: @Hans: Well, it's all relative, in a recent project I rewrote, the previous developers had used Excel automation to parse csv files (open up the file in Excel, copy the 32,000 first rows * 12 columns, cell by cell to a multidim array in the C# app), it took about 12 minutes to load the average 300 line file into memory. So comparatively I don't feel that this is too bad :)

Comment: Hmya, *everything* is relative to that I suppose.

Comment: Luckily the files aren't that big, but there are a lot of them. Maybe the easiest to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder` is a lot less flexible when it comes to searching & removing from. It's used as a helper to speed up concatenation as `"string" + "another string"` is a very costly operation.

I would suggest using `.ToString()` then `Regex.Replace` with a compiled regular expression with flags set to allow multiline.

You'll probably want a search pattern of:

```
(\n[\w-\n]*\n)
```

And you replace it with the empty string.

Check out [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) for a great .NET Regular expression tool.

Comment: I'll give it a try, and thanks for the tip on the RegEx tool.